# how to Parse data in an Android APP communicating with a ELM327

Tags: android, elm327

I am using a ELM327 to retrieve data from a can bus running CAN  with11 bit Headers
I am connecting the ELM via a  USB OTG cable to connect to a Android Device and using the FTDI d2xx.jar to interface to the device
When issuing the ATMA command I get data
The data comes in a continuous stream in the format 
3601122334455667788 361112233445566778899 362112233445566778899. this is never ending
At the moment I am reading data from the buffer at 64 byte lengths
Then removing data either side of the spaces
So I end up with one string
361112233445566778899
Which I can then get the values I require 
But I end up missing data
What is a better way to parse this continuous stream of data?
I am only new to this programing and am struggling a bit.